# Generating an html file from a master page created in the Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, html

I created a new master page by copying the current `oslo.master` in the SharePoint Designer to add breadcrumbs to the oslo layout (following this [link](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/).

I noticed that it did not generate an html file like the other master pages have. Is there anyway I can get this custom master page to generate an html file?

Comment: Did you copy the oslo.master file or the oslo.html file?

Comment: the oslo.master

Comment: Copy the oslo.html instead, a .master file should automatically be created for the copy when you do.